# How to license a software library using the Apache license?

Tags: android, licensing

I made an android library and published it on GitHub as an open source library. Now I want to add the Apache license to it, but I don't know how to apply for the license.

How can I get the Apache license for my Android library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's free to use for everyone.
You just need to add [NOTICE](https://www.apache.org/legal/src-headers.html#notice) and [LICENSE](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt) files to the repo like the [official doc says](https://infra.apache.org/apply-license.html#new). Also, it's recommended to have [a brief copyright header](https://www.apache.org/legal/src-headers.html#headers) for each source file that is licensed under Apache2 license.

Comment: Which extension I use to create LICENSE or NOTICE file? is it .txt file?

Comment: Without any extension. As the [doc says](https://infra.apache.org/apply-license.html#license-file-name). But you can use .txt. It's possible too.